# Eclipse CDT build generated for simplest possible project does not set include path correctly

Tags: c++, eclipse

Eclipse: Kepler; CDT: 8.3.0

I just started using Eclipse CDT for a C++ project. I just used UI to add a new empty C++ class and associated header file to the project automatically. Then I press the build button. Build fails. The build scripts Eclipse CDT generated fail due to a simple issue of not setting an include path:

```
Building file: ../Foo.cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Foo.d" -MT"Foo.d" -o "Foo.o" "../Foo.cpp"
../Foo.cpp:8:17: fatal error: Foo.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Foo.o] Error 1
```

It's building in the subdir `Debug/` (that is the default build configuration CDT setup). If I go into the `Debug/` dir and just add "-I../" to the `g++` command above it works. The build scripts Eclipse CDT creates are failing to find the very source files CDT initialized for me. Why is this failing? Seems really silly. How do I fix it?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have not edited the auto-generated `Foo.cpp`? Please post that file in your question.

Comment: 100%. I literally: started a new project >> new class >> new stub main() >> build, without touching anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to look at that could be the cause:

1. Make sure you are using `#include "Foo.h"` and not `#include <Foo.h>`, quotes vs. brackets.
2. Try removing the `.h` as in `#include "Foo"`.
3. Make sure your `.h` file is in the `src` folder and not outside of it. Since you said you had to add `-I ../` to `Debug` than this most likely is your problem. The `Foo.h` file is outside of the folder where the rest of your project's `.h` files are.
4. Check that Eclipse is automatically creating the Makefile and not expecting you to generate it. This most likely is not the case for you.

It is most likely something simple that was missed. I've run into these little issues in Eclipse on a regular basis.

## Edit

From your comment it was #1 that was the solution to your problem. If Eclipse is automatically generating `#include <Foo.h>` instead of `#include "Foo.h"` when it is creating both the `.h` and `.cpp` for a class then that is a bug with Eclipse.

Comment: Oh. Yep. CDT autogend with '#include <Foo.h>', not '#include "Foo.h"'. But why would it do that? Is there some configuration option?

Comment: You use `#include <Foo.h>` for standard header files (e.g. stdio.h, etc.), but since you used `-I ../`, `Foo.h` is now considered a standard header file. Standard header files are available all throughout your project folder but I would recommend doing that only if you will use the same header file in other projects. If not, just copy the header file in the same folder as the C source file where it's used and use `#include "Foo.h"` instead.

Comment: Since I answered your question, based on your comment, can you mark this as answered?

Comment: @RowenChumacera "You use #include <Foo.h>" yeah I know you do, which is why its strange that eclipse would generate a project .cpp+.h using #include <Foo.h>.

Comment: @user2205930 "If Eclipse is automatically generating #include <Foo.h> instead of #include "Foo.h" when it is creating both the .h and .cpp for a class then that is a bug with Eclipse." It is. So it is a known eclipse bug? Or is it my config? Does eclipse do this for you?

Comment: @S.Pinkus I downloaded Kepler, created an empty C++ project and added a class named Foo. The include statement used `#include "Foo.h"`. I used version 8.3.0.201402142303.

Comment: @S.Pinkus I do not have this issue. Try creating a new empty C++ project and add a Foo class and see what happens. If the problem persists then uninstall Eclipse, download a new/fresh version and install. Try again and see if the problem persists. In the wizard just type `Foo` for the class name and click finish.

Comment: That is exactly what I did as I described above. This is what eclipse is doing by default. Ah well. Staying with QtCreator :).